# MFC: Emdedded child dialog is not showing up within parent dialog

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, embed

I came across a [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4087/How-to-implement-a-scrollable-child-dialog) showing how to embed a child dialog within a parent dialog using MFC. I am using Visual Studio 2015. My setup is as follows. Using the Visual Studio MFC Application Wizard to create a new MFC Visual C++ Project called `MFCApplication3`, I select a **Dialog based** application where MFC is used in a **Shared DLL**. Using boilerplate code, I have a simple Thick Frame Dialog, no maximize or minimize box.

In my resource view, I go to my Dialog editor to edit the main dialog. I add a picture control with a blank area in the center and name it `IDC_STATIC`. This will simply be used as a placeholder for my child dialog that I wish to embed. It looks like:

[image: MFC Basic Dialog with Placeholder]

Still in the resource view, I create a new Dialog. I call it IDD_CHILD. I add some components. It looks like this:

[image: MFC Dialog no border]

Now back in the Solution Explorer, I add a class using the Add Class wizard, selecting to add an MFC Class. The class name is `CChildDialog`, with a base class of `CDialog`, and I use the already generated `IDD_CHILD` as the Dialog ID. It generates the `.cpp` and associated `.h` file. In the constructor of `CChildDialog`, I add a call to the `Create` function so the constructor becomes:

```
CChildDialog::CChildDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(IDD_CHILD, pParent)
{
    Create(IDD_CHILD, pParent);
}
```

Now I modify the dialog code generated automatically when I created the project. In `CMFCApplication3Dlg.h`, I add a `private` member of type `CChildDialog*` called `m_childDlg`, and `#include` the associated header file. In `CMFCApplication3Dlg.cpp`, I add this to the `OnInitDialog` function prior to the `return` statement:

```
CRect rc;
GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC)->GetWindowRect(rc);
ScreenToClient(&rc);

m_childDlg = new CChildDialog(this);
m_childDlg->MoveWindow(rc);
```

Now I build the solution, run it, but it looks like it does in the first picture. A blank placeholder spot for a child dialog, but no child dialog. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out (while composing this question) that the answer to my problem was two properties I need to set while in the resource view. When I have the child dialog open (`IDD_CHILD`), within the properties pane, I need to set the following properties:

- **Style**: Child
- **Visible**: TRUE

(I am not sure why Visible defaults to FALSE in this case). Making those two changes, voila! I get my embedded dialog:

[image: MFC Dialog with Child Dialog]

Comment: The "Visible" defaults to `FALSE` because the common use for those dialog boxes is in a Tab Control, where multiple boxes occupy the same space and are shown as needed, IMHO